# Retrieving data based on sequential conditions in mongodb

Tags: mongodb-query

I have the following problem in mongodb 4.2.0

Consider this a collection like this

```
[

    {a:1,b:1,c:1},
    {a:1,b:2,c:5},
    {a:1,b:3,c:1},

    {a:2,b:1,c:1},
    {a:2,b:2,c:1},
    {a:2,b:3,c:5},
    {a:2,b:4,c:1},
    {a:2,b:5,c:1},

    {a:3,b:1,c:1},
    {a:3,b:2,c:1},
    {a:3,b:3,c:1},
    {a:3,b:5,c:5},
    {a:3,b:7,c:1},

    {a:4,b:3,c:5},
    {a:4,b:5,c:1},

    {a:5,b:2,c:2},
    {a:5,b:4,c:5},
    {a:5,b:5,c:1},


]
```

Is it possible to find all records b = 5 where among all records that have the same value for a, the record with the largest b value lower than b = 5 has a c value equal to 5? Note that b may not be numeric (string/timestamp) but the data can always be ordered, furthermore, for any records sharing the same value for a, b values are distinct.

In the data above, I'd only like to retrieve

```
[
    {a:4,b:3,c:5},
    {a:4,b:5,c:1},
    {a:5,b:2,c:2},
    {a:5,b:4,c:5},
    {a:5,b:5,c:1}
]
```

though the following is fine as well.

```
[
    {a:4,b:5,c:1},
    {a:5,b:5,c:1}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **mongodb version 4.2**, one option is:

1. `$sort` according to `b` so we can have the items sorted inside each group
2. `$group` according to `a` and keep the `b` and `c` values on each grouped document
3. Use `$reduce` to add index to each item on `items`
4. Add another field called `bItem` for the item `b` you want to match
5. Keep only groups which have such an item
6. Find the item with the closet `b` value under the wanted value, using the index of `bItem`
7. `$match` only document where `c` value of the item before is with the wanted value.
8. Format the answer

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$sort: {b: -1}},
  {$group: {
      _id: "$a",
      items: {$push: {b: "$b", c: "$c" }}
  }},
  {$project: {
      items: {$reduce: {
          input: "$items",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {$concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              [{"$mergeObjects": [
                    "$$this",
                    {index: {$size: "$$value"}}
              ]}]
          ]}
      }}
  }},
  {$project: {
      bItem: {$filter: {
          input: "$items",
          cond: {$eq: ["$$this.b", 5]}
      }},
      items: 1
  }},
  {$match: {"bItem.0": {$exists: true}}},
  {$project: {
      bItem: {$first: "$bItem"},
      itemBefore: {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$items",
          {$add: [{$first: "$bItem.index"}, 1]}
      ]}
  }},
  {$match: {"itemBefore.c": 5}},
  {$project: {
      a: "$_id",
      b: "$bItem.b",
      c: "$bItem.c"
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MAYXEdIwU8y)

This is much easier since **mongodb version 5.0** with `$setWindowFields`:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$setWindowFields: {
      partitionBy: "$a",
      sortBy: {b: -1},
      output: {lastItemC: {
          $push: "$c",
          window: {documents: [0, 1]}
      }}
  }},
  {$match: {b: 5, "lastItemC.1": 5}},
  {$unset: ["_id", "lastItemC"]}
])
```

Comment: Very instructive. Thank you